# Screensavers With XNA and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, screensaver, creation

I'm fairly sure you can create screensavers with.NET but are there any tutorials on doing so? and how well can you make XNA screensavers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A screensaver is just an executable named that has been renamed '.scr' :) So yes, you can make one in whatever language you like, pretty much.

Comment: Place in the Windows folder, with the 'scr' executable.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a nice and small tutorial that explains how to create a [screensaver with C#](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html).

As already mentioned, a screensaver is just an executable with an `.scr` file extension instead of `.exe`. Additionally, if you want to create a useful screensaver, you *should* support these [command-line arguments](http://www.wischik.com/scr/howtoscr.html#CommandLineArguments):

`/c`, `/c:HWND`, `/c HWND`: Configuration mode where `HWND` is the handle to the window that should be used as the parent.
`/p`, `/p HWND`: Preview mode where `HWND` is the handle to the parent window.
`/s`: Run in full-screen mode

Answer (score 4):

James O'Meara has created a nice XNA Screensaver Starter Kit which is a great resource for learning how to create a screensaver with XNA. Detail including the downloads are in the XNA forum [here](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/254.aspx). I recommend reading the comments too, as there are some good tips on how to show the screensaver in the preview window also.

Answer (score 4):

Today, I have posted an updated starter kit at the XNA forum [here](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/254/269045.aspx#269045). The update consists of XNA GS 3.1 support, working preview and modal configuration dialog.

Tonight, I will write an article describing the different aspects here: http://doktormadsen.dk/wp/xna-screensaver-kit/.

Update: the article is now drafted and comments are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple tutorial try [Useful screensavers](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/350-useful-screensavers.html)  which also explains how to do the preview mode which is generally left out of any accounts

Answer (score 1):

There is an XNA 3.1 screen saver kit on the second page of this thread.

http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/254.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've written a fully functional screen saver that takes into account some of the more obscure details that they don't normally tell you about. You can view the [source code](https://github.com/steveniles/MandelZoom) and a [wiki](https://github.com/steveniles/MandelZoom/wiki) explaining the details.